# Identify the last edited sheet via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a method or way of identifying the last edited sheet in a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

You would have checked the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) and found that no such method exists.

To accomplish this, you would need to write a proactive script to:

- Use an `onEdit()` trigger function to identify the occurrence and source of edits.
- Record the details in a non-volatile store; perhaps another spreadsheet.
- Respond to queries about the last edited sheet.